# pyspark explode json array of dictionary items with key/values pairs into columns

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, nested

I have a spark dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I want to flatten the columns.

Result should look like this:

[image]

Data:

```json
{
    "header": {
        "message-id": "ID:EL2-202103221753-77777777-88888-9999999999-1:2:1:1:1",
        "reply-to": "queue://CaseProcess.v2",
        "timestamp": "2021-03-22T20:07:27"
    },
    "properties": {
        "property": [
            {
                "name": "ELIS_EXCEPTION_MSG",
                "value": "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records"
            },
            {
                "name": "ELIS_MESSAGE_ORIG_TIMESTAMP_MILLIS",
                "value": "1616458043704"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first rename columns in header then explode `properties.property` array then pivot and group columns.

Here is an example that produces your wanted result:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()

    data = {
        "header": {
            "message-id": "ID:EL2-202103221753-77777777-88888-9999999999-1:2:1:1:1",
            "reply-to": "queue://CaseProcess.v2",
            "timestamp": "2021-03-22T20:07:27",
        },
        "properties": {
            "property": [
                {
                    "name": "ELIS_EXCEPTION_MSG",
                    "value": "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records",
                },
                {
                    "name": "ELIS_MESSAGE_ORIG_TIMESTAMP_MILLIS",
                    "value": "1616458043704",
                },
            ]
        },
    }

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json.dumps(data)]))

    df = df.select(
        F.col("header.message-id").alias("message-id"),
        F.col("header.reply-to").alias("reply-to"),
        F.col("header.timestamp").alias("timestamp"),
        F.col("properties"),
    )

    df = df.withColumn("propertyexploded", F.explode("properties.property"))
    df = df.withColumn("propertyname", F.col("propertyexploded")["name"])
    df = df.withColumn("propertyvalue", F.col("propertyexploded")["value"])
    df = (
        df.groupBy("message-id", "reply-to", "timestamp")
        .pivot("propertyname")
        .agg(F.first("propertyvalue"))
    )

    df.printSchema()
    df.show()
```

Result:

```
root                                                                            
 |-- message-id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- reply-to: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ELIS_EXCEPTION_MSG: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ELIS_MESSAGE_ORIG_TIMESTAMP_MILLIS: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
|          message-id|            reply-to|          timestamp|  ELIS_EXCEPTION_MSG|ELIS_MESSAGE_ORIG_TIMESTAMP_MILLIS|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
|ID:EL2-2021032217...|queue://CaseProce...|2021-03-22T20:07:27|The AWS Access Ke...|                     1616458043704|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad.  I will give this a try.
I used flatMap and was able to refer to the columns and change it accordingly.
However, your solution stays with DataFrame which would be more efficient.
I am going to give it a try and reply back.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vlad.  I tried your option and it was successful.
In your solution, the properties.property['name'] is dynamic and I liked that.
The only drawback is that the # of rows get multiplied by the # of properties in which when I had 3 rows, it created 36 rows in the flattened df.  Of course you pivot back to 3 rows.
The problem i faced is that all the properties get repeated x*12 times.  it would have been fine if the properties were small.  But I have 2 columns in the stack which can be up to 2K-20K and I have some queues which go over 100K rows.  Repeating that over and over again seems a bit of an overkill for my process.

However, I found another solution, with a drawback where the property name can be hard-coded but the repeat of rows is eliminated.
Here is what I ended up using:

```
XXX = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [( x[1]["destination"].replace("queue://", ""), 
                                      x[1]["message-id"].replace("ID:", ""), 
                                      x[1]["delivery-mode"], 
                                      x[1]["expiration"], 
                                      x[1]["priority"], 
                                      x[1]["redelivered"], 
                                      x[1]["timestamp"], 
                                      y[0]["value"], 
                                      y[1]["value"], 
                                      y[2]["value"], 
                                      y[3]["value"], 
                                      y[4]["value"], 
                                      y[5]["value"], 
                                      y[6]["value"], 
                                      y[7]["value"], 
                                      y[8]["value"], 
                                      y[9]["value"], 
                                      y[10]["value"], 
                                      y[11]["value"],
                                      x[0],
                                      x[3],
                                      x[4],
                                      x[5]
                                     ) for y in x[2]
                                    ])\
                  .toDF(["queue",
                          "message_id",
                          "delivery_mode",
                          "expiration",
                          "priority",
                          "redelivered",
                          "timestamp",
                          "ELIS_EXCEPTION_MSG", 
                          "ELIS_MESSAGE_ORIG_TIMESTAMP_MILLIS", 
                          "ELIS_MESSAGE_RETRY_COUNT",
                          "ELIS_MESSAGE_ORIG_TIMESTAMP",
                          "ELIS_MDC_TRACER_ID",
                          "tracestate",
                          "ELIS_ROOT_CAUSE_EXCEPTION_MSG",
                          "traceparent",
                          "ELIS_MESSAGE_TYPE",
                          "ELIS_EXCEPTION_CLASS",
                          "newrelic",
                          "ELIS_EXCEPTION_TRACE",
                          "body",
                          "partition_0",
                          "partition_1",
                          "partition_2"
                         ])
                                    
print(f"... type(XXX): {type(XXX)}  | df.count(): {df.count()} | XXX.count(): {XXX.count()}")
```

output: ... type(XXX): <class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'> | df.count(): 3 | XXX.count(): 3

My column structure is from activeMQ API extracts which means that the column structure is consistent  and its OK for my use case to hard-code the column names in the flattened_df